# Data cloning into 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

I am working with MATLAB, and I would have the following problem. I have the following matrix of random numbers `rand(200,200)` 
and I need to create  a 3D matrix with the following structure `3D_mat(r,s,p)` with 15 layers (`p=15`), where each layer will contain the  given data `rand(200,200)`. Perhaps, it is easy task, but I am MATLAB beginner.

Comment: It is very unlikely that you can call a variable `3D_mat` (cannot start with a number)

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746999/most-efficient-way-for-repeating-a-vector-in-matlab (modulo replacing 1d arrays by 2d arrays), which also includes some timings.

Comment: @Christian Clason Yes, and link you point at is "so 2013"

Comment: Same data for 15 layers? Or each layer with different random numbers?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most efficient way to do this in MATLAB, but the following works for me in Octave:

```
A=rand(200,200);
for i=1:15
  B(:,:,i)=A;
end
```

And, I think it should work fine in MATLAB as well. If your dimensions get a lot bigger or you have to create the 3D matrix frequently, there are probably much more efficient was to accomplish this.

Comment: You can also use `repmat`: `B=repmat(A,1,1,15)`. If the dimensions are a lot bigger, it would make sense to *not* construct `B` at all and instead use broadcasting (look for `bsxfun` in the online help) whenever you need to do something with `B`.

Comment: @ Christian Clason To maintain compatibility with older versions of MATLAB, it is better to use repmat(A,[1,1,15]) which will work in new and old versions of MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three options: with `repmat` or `bsxfun`, two functions evoked by @Christian Clason. On some versions of Matlab (notably older than 2013, as can be seen from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746999/most-efficient-way-for-repeating-a-vector-in-matlab), `bsxfun` was faster, and if not the case, is believed to use less memory (useful if you get much bigger than $200\times 200\times15$). The last one plays with indexing.

```
nRow = 200;
nCol = 200;
nDep = 15;

r = rand(nRow,nCol);
o = zeros(nRow,nCol,nDep); % Not bad to initialize

% Choose one
o = repmat(r,1,1,nDep); % repmat version
o = bsxfun(@times,ones(1, 1 , nDep),r); % bsxfun version
o = r(:,:,ones(1, 1 , nDep)); % multiple-indexing version
```

In my case (Matlab2013b), repmat is $2/3$ faster than the two others, for several matrix sizes and repetition depth (including yours). According to some testimonies, since  a novel coding of `repmat` exist in Matlab2013b and above, `bsxfun` indeed can be slower.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't recommending to use `bsxfun` for *creating* `o` -- that would completely defeat the purpose. Instead, when you want to do (e.g.) `D=o.*C`, you do `D=bsxfun(@times,C,r)` (and similarly for other operations). But as I said, I doubt you'll see much difference for the sizes in this example.

Comment: @Christian Clason Actually, I never used `bsxfun` before, that was an opportunity for me to try it. I'll be aware of its convenience in the future